# Creating Interactive Image on Website

Tags: image, dictionary, interactive, area

I'm doing some research to create an interactive image on a website. I come up with one of the solutions to use the map and area tag for the background img tag. But, since there will be a lot of small area in the image. I think that it will be tedious to use the map and area tag to define the area one by one.

I also think to crop the interactive image, and make it a single another image. Thus, separating it from the background image. But using a separate image for each interactive area is also tedious since every interactive area/image is different from each other, so I have to crop each image and ends up with each image has different source.

Is there a best practice to do this? I'd really appreciate for any suggestion from anyone.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Dreamweaver to create the ares on the image map.
No need to write any code, just open the page with the image and use the visual tool to create any number of super complex areas in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look forward to the Dreamweaver Solution.